# Connection Timed Out to Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Getting below exception while trying to delete an object in amazon S3. Can someone throw some light on what is causing this and how to resolve this issue?

Looking at the exception it looks like client side exception. Is it because that particular thread unable to get a connection from connection pool?

**Using Below Maven Dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

**Exception Details:**

> software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to  bucketname.s3.region.amazonaws.com.cn:443 [bucketname.s3.region.amazonaws.com.cn/52.82.188.56] failed: connect timed out at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException$BuilderImpl.build(SdkClientException.java:97) at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage$RetryExecutor.handleThrownException(RetryableStage.java:140) at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage$RetryExecutor.execute(RetryableStage.java:96) at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:64) at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:44) at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:205) at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:51) at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:33) at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.executeWithTimer(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:79) at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:60) at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42) at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:205) at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:205) at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:37) at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:26) at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.AmazonSyncHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonSyncHttpClient.java:240) at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.invoke(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:96) at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:120) at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:73) at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.SdkSyncClientHandler.execute(SdkSyncClientHandler.java:44) at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler.execute(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:55) at software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.DefaultS3Client.deleteObject(DefaultS3Client.java:868)

Comment: Can you confirm if your credentials are correct. Also are you under a corporate proxy

Comment: It is referencing `bucketname.s3.region.amazonaws.com`. This suggests that an incorrect region has been provided, because there is no region called `region`. (I presume the bucket name was not `bucketname` too?)

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein , I am using proper values in my code.. In this post I have edited dummy values

Comment: Yes @NaveenKulkarni, Credentials are correct and I am under corporate proxy. This used to work before, suddenly this error is coming.

Comment: @AnilKumarKonam confirm if the certificate is expired or not

Comment: @NaveenKulkarni I am not aware of how and where these certificates are configured. Can you please share me a link to understand this more.